# Tkinter doesn't play nicely with multiprocessing

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

The following code hangs without doing anything in `Python 3.2.2` in Linux:

```py
import tkinter
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    label = tkinter.Label(root)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()

p = Process(target=f)
p.start()
```

The only information I have found about this problem is [issue 5527](http://bugs.python.org/issue5527), in which it is noted that the problem is with `tkinter` being imported before the process is forked, and that it can be fixed by importing `tkinter` inside the function `f`, and that the problem occurs in Linux but not Solaris.

What exactly is causing this problem, and is it a bug? Is there any workaround other than to import `tkinter` locally everywhere I need it (which isn't very Pythonic)?  Do any other modules have similar issues with multiprocessing?

Comment: -0.  You know the problem.  You know that a bug report has been filed.  You know the workaround.  The only other major question is "Do any other modules have similar issues with multiprocessing?", which seems a little open ended.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I don't know the problem - I have no idea what tkinter is doing that fails to work here, or why it is platform-dependent.  The bug report was filed over 3 years ago, and there is no sign that anybody knows why (or under exactly what conditions) this happens or how to fix it.  Maybe my last question should have read "are there any other standard library modules that cannot be imported before forking a process", which is a bit more specific.

Comment: @James please update your question with your OS and Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the problem has to do with the connection to the X server (usually a socket). If this is created before the process is `fork()`-ed, the child process inherits this connection. But if it tries to use it, the X server gets confused.

After a cursory look at at `Tkinter.py`, it looks like maybe calling the `NoDefaultRoot` function before starting the process *might* be useful. It all depends on *when* the connection to the X server is made.

Otherwise importing Tkinter after the fork seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2013, there are some additional comments on the bug report that give more insight into what the actual problem is.

http://bugs.python.org/issue5527#msg194848
http://bugs.python.org/issue5527#msg195480

Based on the above, I'm guessing something like the following is happening:  Tkinter is not thread safe, so (for whatever reason) Tkinter wants to know which thread is the main thread.  Tkinter assumes that the main thread when the Tkinter module is loaded will also be the main thread for program execution.  When you fork or multiprocess after loading Tkinter, this assumption is broken.  (For example, after a fork, the remembered main thread is in the parent, not the child.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a thread started, just do root.mainloop() after it and it should work fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32635299)

Answer (score 0):

Windows-only answer:
My guess is that this code works, though I don't know the details.
Multiple windows running in separate processes communicate using queues.

```
import tkinter
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f1(q):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    button_wid = tkinter.Button(root, text="Get Entry Text", command=lambda : get_entry(q))
    button_wid.pack()
    root.mainloop()

def get_entry(q):
    try:
        print(q.get_nowait())
    except:
        pass

def put_Q_entry_text(q, text, event=None):
    q.put(text)

def f2(q):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    entry_wid = tkinter.Entry(root)
    entry_wid.pack()
    entry_wid.bind("<Return>", lambda event: put_Q_entry_text(q, entry_wid.get()))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=f1, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=f2, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```