# Make _tkinter.createfilehandler work again (or provide a workaround)

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got some old Python scripts which used a different version of `tkinter` than the current systems are equipped with.  Back in the old days, a method named `_tkinter.createfilehandler()` existed and worked.  With the current versions this returns with a `RuntimeError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/text.py", line 513, in <module>
    tkinter.createfilehandler(pipe_r, READABLE, drain_pipe)
RuntimeError: _tkinter.createfilehandler not supported for threaded Tcl
```

The script I'm trying to get to run is this (shortened version of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from Tkinter import *

(pipe_r, pipe_w) = os.pipe()

# ...

def drain_pipe(a, b):
    # handle data from pipe_r
    # ...

tkinter.createfilehandler(pipe_r, READABLE, drain_pipe)

tk.mainloop()
```

Is there a simple way to get this running again?  I'm sure there is a way to convert the scripts (or maybe write them anew based on a different paradigm), but I'd be happy with a hack to not have to change very much (maybe there's a switch to enable this again somehow) because I've got several such scripts and would prefer not to have to patch a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `tk` is a `Tk()` object, then use `tk.createfilehandler` instead.

Comment: That's usually the right thing to do anyway, but… does that actually solve this problem? If his `createfilehandler` refuses to work with threaded Tcl, I suspect the same will be true no matter which way you call it.

Comment: It is a solution I read about sometime ago whilst helping a colleague... he never came back so I am assuming it worked. There's a thread on the subject on mail.python.org.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Looking at [the code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_tkinter.c#l2427), if you call it without having the `tcl_lock`, it's still OK if you have `self` (that is, if you call the global function instead of the instance method), because then it can use that `self` to do the `CHECK_TCL_APPARTMENT` stuff instead.

Comment: This should mean that `tk.createfilehandler` works iff it's called from the same thread as `tk = Tk()` and `tk.mainloop()`. Since that doesn't even make sense for `tkinter.createfilehandler`, it makes sense that wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: At first sight this seems to work :-)  (No exception anymore.)   But the scripts are old and haven't been used in a while; with that simple patch (exactly the kind of fix I was looking for!) one isn't displaying anything right now (but also not the error anymore), so I will have a look on how to fix the other issues.

Comment: I still had to solve an issue with `fork()` (solved using the idea given in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755641/why-doesnt-tkinter-play-nicely-with-multiprocessing/12232154)) first, but now the old scripts are working again!  Thank you!