# Multiprocessing Python Core Foundation Error

Tags: python, concurrency, tkinter, multiprocessing

So I'm having trouble with launching multiple processes in Python. I am going to use one process to run a download and another process to display a progress bar. Right now, I am working on making the progress bar process, but I keep getting this weird error. I think it has to do with the fact I'm using Mac OS X.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process
class Application(tk.Frame):
      def __init__(self, master = None):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
          self.grid()
          self.setup()
      def setup(self):
          self.label = tk.Label(self, text = "Progress Bar")
          self.label.grid()
          self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, cursor = 'arrow', height = 400, width = 400)
          self.canvas.grid()
          self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,399,20,fill = 'white')
          self.canvas.grid()
def appStart():         
   app = Application()
   app.master.title("Progress Bar")
   app.mainloop()

p = Process(target = appStart)
p.start()
```

And here is the error:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

So yeah, how do I solve this problem. I really want to use the multiprocessing library because its really easy and simple to use. I'm also somewhat of a beginner with regards to concurrency, so the lower-level APIs would be really complicated for me. I need to use multiple processes because Python cant run multiple threads at the same time. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't separate a GUI into two processes like this. You'll need to keep all GUI code in the master process, and have your other process communicate with it via a queue.

Answer (score 0):

In OS 10.8.5 I have the same problem with your code.

Try this one:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def appStart():
     import Tkinter as tk

     class Application(tk.Frame):
         def __init__(self, master = None):
             tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
             self.grid()
             self.setup()

         def setup(self):
             self.label = tk.Label(self, text = "Progress Bar")
             self.label.grid()
             self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, cursor = 'arrow', height = 400, width = 400)
             self.canvas.grid()
             self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,399,20,fill = 'white')
             self.canvas.grid()

     app = Application()
     app.master.title("Progress Bar")
     app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target = appStart)
    p.start()
```

In Mac and linux it seems that you must only import Tkinter after you have started (forked) your processes, here I've used your "appStart" function as your Tkinter wrapper to create the process.

Some refs:
[Python Tkinter application causes fork() / exec() error on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143866/1956309)
[Why doesn't tkinter play nicely with multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10755641/1956309)